# How to autofill specific cell when any next cell is filled

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|    Date    |  Col1   |  Col2   |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 2018-01-01 | Value 1 | Value 1 |
| 2018-01-01 | Value 2 | Value 2 |
| 2018-01-01 | Value 3 | Value 3 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

I want to autofill `Date` column's cell with current date, when any of the `Col1` and `Col2` is filled in that row.

How can I do that, Is there any formula or need to write script ?

Comment: No need for a script. Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((W10:W13<>"")+(X10:X13<>""),TODAY(),""))
```

and then give the desired date format to the results from the menu.
*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`TODAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: I got this error `Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings`, and also could you please explain the ranges - Why multiple `W10:W13` and `X10:X13`

Comment: Let assume that I want to fill `A:1`  when any of the cell from range `B:1` to `D:1` is filled, What will be the range in `arrayformula`

Comment: Please have a look at the sreenshot.

Comment: Thanks It worked